# how to get variation in a product id

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I'm not getting a return on the color and size, only the product name is coming.
And yes my request.POST['color'] and request.POST['size'] are receiving the values, but in the form of names and not in id.

```
def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        variation_list = []
    
        if request.method == "POST":
            color = request.POST['color']
            size = request.POST['size']
            
            try:
                variation = Variation.objects.get(product=product, color__name__exact=color, size__name__exact=size)
                variation_list.append(variation)
            except:
                pass
    
        return HttpResponse(variation_list)
```

[HttpResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBhw2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because HttpResponse is just going to return Raw text you must explicitly say what you want to show, it can't do full objects and it's probably just doing the Models's `__str__` method currently

Example:

```py
o = ''
for i in variation_list:
    s += '{0},{1},{2}\n'.format(i.name, i.color.name, i.size.name)

return HttpResponse(s)
```

Or you could just render a template, like normal, with just a loop like:

```html
{% for i in variation_list %}
{{i.name}},{{i.color}}, etc
{% endfor %}
```

Another Possibility, that I personally use a Json:

```py
d = []
for i in variation_list:
    d.append({
        'name': i.name,
        'color': i.color.name,
        'size': i.size.name,
    })
import json
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(d), content_type="application/json")
```